# How to call a function on edit icon in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

My project angular version:

Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.7

I m working with ag-grid and I want to edit a record.  and  I call a function on edit icon but give an error.

Uncaught Referance Error: editfunction is not defined
at HTMLElement.onclick

partymastercomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendService } from '../backend.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-partymaster',
  templateUrl: './partymaster.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partymaster.component.css']
})
export class PartymasterComponent implements OnInit {

    PartyMstId: any;
    PartyCode: any;
    PartyName: any;

    partylist: any;

    constructor(public myservice: BackendService) { }

    columnDefs = [
      {
          headerName: "Edit",
          field: "icon",
          width: 100,
          //id: this.PartyMstId,
          cellRenderer: function (params)
          {
              return  '<button (click)="editfunction()"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>'
          }
      },
      { headerName: 'PartyMstId', field: 'PartyMstId', sortable: true, filter: true/*, checkboxSelection: true*/ },
      { headerName: 'PartyCode', field: 'PartyCode', sortable: true, filter: true },
      { headerName: 'PartyName', field: 'PartyName', sortable: true, filter: true },

 ];

  editfunction() {
      console.log("call this edit function");
  }
}
```

partymastercomponent.html

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"
                 class="ag-theme-balham"
                 [rowData]="partylist"                   
                 rowSelection="multiple"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

how to call a function on edit icon click??

When I Click Edit Icon:

[image]

When I put the Button and when press the button not display the log:

```
 return '<button (click)="editfunction()" >Click This</button>'
```

Comment: Do like this (click)="editfunction()"

Comment: @MustafaKunwa thanks give suggestion I already try this but not work or not get any error

Comment: Can you share stackblitz?

Comment: @MustafaKunwa can u tell me what should I do?

Comment: create your [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/) here and share

Answer (score 0):

```
return '<span><i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="editfunction()"></i></span>'
```

Comment: @S Rana thanks your answer but not work your code give an error when I press f12  not get any error

Comment: @S Rana browser did not give any error or browser not print this log("call this edit function") 
 when I press the edit icon

Comment: @S Rana can u tell me what should I do?

Comment: Please share a demo link. This will help us understand it

Answer (score 0):

Check [official demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-single-click-editing-renderer)

Modified [plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/BhPCPa?p=preview)

Instead of `getRenderer()` `function` you can create custom [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) component and inject it to [`gridOptions`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-components/#component-registration) `components` or `frameworkComponents`

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474327/4483102)
[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52756127/4483102)

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

`return '<button (click)="editfunction()"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>'`

The outer element can be span, div, button or whatever but I believe you usually place the click function on this and not on the icon itself.

In your class your function is

```
editfunction() {
       console.log("call this edit function");
       //i want to edit a record but how but function call is not working
```

but should be

```
editfunction() {
       console.log("call this edit function");
       //i want to edit a record but how but function call is not working
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the element in your view what does it contain?

Comment: In the code you're showing your class is missing a closing `}`. Fix this and try again

Comment: I closing my class properly but function is not calling.

Comment: Please edit your code to show us the correct closing tags!

Comment: And could you please inspect the element and paste the content here? Thx

Comment: Please right click on the button/icon and choose `Inspect`. What does the HTML show you here?

Either the HTML is incorrect in the view or the function is for some reason not called. I suspect the former.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206430/discussion-between-raju-bhai-and-johan-faerch).

Comment: Function will not call cuz you should use inline renderer only for html (without any functionality)